# Probability question (coin toss)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Q: We flip a fair coin many times. Find the probability that we have more heads than tails for the first time at the 11th flip.

I first thought you had to solve it using negative binomial distribution, but I realized it would lead to overcounting since just focusing on the 6th head at the 11th flip includes many cases where there are more heads than tails 'before' the 11th flip.

I already know the answer, which is given below. But I have no idea how to derive that combination. I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me the logic that leads to the solution. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want the first time you have more heads than tails at the 11'th step, you have that at the 10th step you have equal number of heads and tails. This means at the end of the 9th step you have one more tails than heads. Further, the first step is a tail.

So if we designate the total number of heads - number of tails as $= t$, we are looking for a path from $t=-1$ after the first step call this point A to $t=-1$ after the 9th step, call this point B, such that path does not cross $t=0$. There are 8 steps here from A to B. The total number of paths in which these 8 steps can be chosen to go from -1 to -1 is $\binom{8}{4}$, each with equal probability. Out of these, some cross 0, let's calculate these.

The number of these paths which cross 0 is computed as follows: Consider the paths that cross 0, all these touch 1. Then let's consider the first point at which they touch 1 and call this C. All paths from A to B via C, can be broken into A to C and C to B. Now reflect the path from C to B about $t=1$ line. Then the new path goes from A(-1 after 1st step) to D(+3 after 9th step). Now the total number of paths from A to D is in bijection with the number of paths from A to B such that they cross $t=0$, or in other words bijection with paths from A to B such that C exists.

We can compute paths from A to D easily. We need to move up by 4H in 8 steps, and therefore we have 6H and 2T in the path. These can be chosen in $\binom{8}{2}$ ways.

Thus now we have the number of paths from $A$ to $B$ such that C does not exist as
\begin{align*}
N(\text{A to B without C}) &= \binom{8}{4} - \binom{8}{2}
\end{align*}
Therefore total number of paths such that the first time we get more heads than tails in the 11 step is the same as the path such that:

1. 1st toss is a tail
2. path such that you go from A to B without touching C
3. 10th and 11th toss are heads.

Since 1. and 3. are deterministic, the number of such paths are same as the number of paths in step 2., which is $\binom{8}{4} - \binom{8}{2}$.

Now the probability of such paths is (number of favorable paths)/(total number of paths for 11 steps).

The total number of paths over 11 steps is $2^{11}$ as each step can be a head or a tail.

Therefore $$\mathbb P(\text{probability of more H than T in 11th step}) = \frac{\binom{8}{4} - \binom{8}{2}}{2^{11}}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a Catalan´s number. You can check it at wiki, there it is better explained why and how is the result as it is.

For your case to happen, there must be head as the last flip. Now, you just want to count a number of routs from point (0,0) to (5,5) on the grid, such that they do not cross the diagonal.